# Create multiple range in SQL from a number series

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I have a database table containing multiple records like

```
fileno  sskNo   Status
246617  186 N
246617  187 N
246617  188 N
246619  189 N
246619  190 N
246617  191 N
246617  192 N
```

I want to display the range to the customer on asp.net page like

```
246617 : 186 to 188
246617 : 191 to 192
246619 : 189 to 190
```

How to generate this? The database is in SQL Server 2008 and the front end is ASp.net using C#.

Also, the database will contain hundreds of thousands of records.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT FileNo, MIN(sskNo) AS minSSKNo, MAX(sskNo) as maxSSKNo FROM Table GROUP BY FileNo
```